# Get-ADDomainController LDAP query

Tags: powershell, active-directory, ldap, ldap-query

I'm using Wireshark to sniff the LDAP query behind this PowerShell cmdlet (which generates some results as expected):

```
Get-ADDomainController -Filter * -Server domain.local
```

However it seems like there is no LDAP communication but rather CLDAP and the filter I see in the request is weird:

```
(&(&(&(DnsDomain=domain.local)(Host=example_hostname))(NtVer=0x20000016))(DnsHostName=example_hostname.domain.local))
```

The CLDAP response only contain "success" but not the actual results. Sending this filter in an LDAP query (using Python) generates no results.

What am I missing here?

Comment: Please show some code and the complete LDAP Query as there are several options for Get-ADDomainController.

Answer (score 0):

I do not know the specifics of the Get-ADDomainController LDAP query.

From the little information provided it appears you are seeing the "[LDAP ping](https://ldapwiki.com/wiki/LDAP%20ping)" process which SHOULD return the "[Netlogon attribute](https://ldapwiki.com/wiki/Netlogon%20attribute)" with various attribute values including the "[DS_FLAG](https://ldapwiki.com/wiki/DS_FLAG)" values.

Can not be sure why there are no "values" but it may be due to either:

- the encoding of the LDAP Request You MUST set the SearchRequest to
- the base of the rootDSE

The response is shown the the LDAP Ping is [displayed in Wireshark](https://www.ixiacom.com/company/blog/following-crumbs-deconstructing-cldap-ddos-reflection-attack), but perhaps may not be properly decoded and will be fragmented due to the size.